# Problems starting MongoDB when installing MongoDB on Windows 7

Tags: windows, mongodb

I am following the tutorial: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows/

I am trying to start mongo db by running the mongod.exe file. I write the following in the command prompt: C:\Program Files\MongoDB 2.6 Standard\bin\mongod.exe

This path exist and contains the file. I have tried to start the command prompt as an administrator. When I write this I get the follwoing feedback (translated from Swedish): C: "Program is not an internal command, external command, a program or command file

Do you have any ideas what I have to do to run the exe file? Please let me know if you need more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use quotes when using the full path or cd to the directory that contains the exe and run it. The spaces in the path are causing the problem